# Terraform loop through json file

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to spin up a storage account in azurerm using terraform and pair it with a key name to encrypt this storage with. But for commodity and future improvement, I would like to set the name of this storage account from a json file. The idea is to set a array in json with `storages name` and `key_name` and in my `azurerm_resources` loop through those values and set them.

The issue I am facing is that I am not able to access the json file. I have configured it as follow.

`tenant.json`

```
{
  "inputs": [
        {
          "tenant-pair": {"tenant-name":  "storage-name", "tenant-key": "key-name"}
        }
      ]
}
```

In my main.tf, following some documentations, I set a `locals` as follow:

```
locals {
  tenant_data = jsondecode("./tenants.json")

}
```

but if I try to flatten this data:

```
locals {
  tenant_data = jsondecode("./tenants.json")
  helper_list = flatten([for v in local.tenant_data.inputs :
    [for tenant_name, tenant_key in v.tenant-pair :
      {
        "tenant_name" = tenant_name
        "tenant_key"  = tenant_key
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

the error I am getting in this code is that the `inputs` is an unresolved reference.

I was wondering how I can access my json file and loop through it?

Thank you very much guys for your help and guidance.

Comment: Did you try with `jsondecode(file("tenants.json"))`?

Answer (score 1):

When you are providing the JSON data value as a file, use the `file` function along with it as below

```
locals {
  tenant_data = jsondecode(file("tenant.json"))
}

output "json" {
  value = element(flatten([for v in local.tenant_data.inputs : v.tenant-pair]), 0)
}
```

**Outputs:**

```
Outputs:

json = {
  "tenant-key" = "key-name"
  "tenant-name" = "storage-name"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. But unfortunately even if I run your exact code. I get the same error "no argument or block type is named"input"

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code what your are trying?

Comment: I did use your same code for testing. exactly the same code mate. when I run terraform I get the error: `Error: Extraneous JSON object property` as it seems it does not recognise the `inputs` in my json file

Comment: Sorry mate, it is working now for some weird reason. It does print the result. Just a clarification. If I have more elements in my json array, how can I print all of them? like If I have 3 `tenant-pairs` and want to loop and print all of them?